# Problem with Turbo Assembler's DIV instruction

Tags: assembly, dos, tasm, dosbox

So there was a problem with a program of mine, which led me to write the following code snippet and test it:

```
        .MODEL   TINY
        .386p
        Kod     SEGMENT USE32
        ORG      100h
        ASSUME   CS:Kod,DS:Kod,SS:Kod
Def:    JMP      Start
        ;        space for data declaration
Start:  MOV      eax,00000010h
        MOV      ecx,0000000Ah
        DIV      ecx
        MOV      eax, 00004C00h
        INT      21h
        Kod      ENDS
        END      Def
```

Suppose I name a file with the above code as `test.asm`.
The compilation under DOSBox Portable using `tasm test.asm` and `tlink /t test.obj` is successful. And then comes the weird problem. Running the COM executable in debug mode using `td test.com` (Turbo Debugger) proceeds succesfully. But then, I ask the Turbo Debugger to reload the program (after pressing F8 one more time) and when reaching the DIV instruction, the program jumps to a different set of instructions which eventualy leads to "Divide by zero". The beginning of this set of instructions is shown below:
[[view the screenshot]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWIpu.png). What is the reason of this quirky phenomenon, and how to make the DIV instruction do its work as in the first debugging cycle? (running `test.com` directly results in DOS freezing). Is this maybe a DOSBox emulator issue?

Comment: `DIV ECX` divides the register pair `EDX:EAX` by `ECX`. In this code, `EDX` does not seem to be initialized. What happens once the missing initialization of `EDX` is added to the code?

Comment: @njuffa Thank you very much. This is at the same time the reason why after reloading the program in Turbo Debugger the behaviour is different (non-zero EDX register value)

Comment: Adding `MOV edx,00000000h` before the DIV instruction solved the problem

Comment: If you want to zero `edx`, `xor edx, edx` is never worse than `mov edx, 0`. `cdq` can save a byte from the code size if you know `eax` is positive.